# NFS Mounts Wrong Share

Tags: nfs, raspbian

I have three Raspberry Pis running Raspbian.  One is serving as an NFS NAS, the other two are load-balanced web servers running NGINX.  The configuration is like this:

On the NAS (10.34.0.40):

```
root@nas:~# cat /etc/exports
/drupal 10.34.0.10(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) 10.34.0.20(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
/wordpress 10.34.0.10(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) 10.34.0.20(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
```

On the WEB1 (10.34.0.10) server:

```
root@web1:~# cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
nas:/drupal     /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal    nfs     hard,intr       0   0
nas:/wordpress  /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress nfs     hard,intr   0   0
```

On the WEB2 (10.34.0.20) server:

```
root@web2:~# cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
nas:/drupal     /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal    nfs     hard,intr   0   0
nas:/wordpress  /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress nfs     hard,intr       0   0
```

The two fstabs are identical (in fact,the two web servers have identical configurations provisioned with ansible).  However, while WEB1 mounts the two mountpoints correctly, WEB2 mounts the nas:/drupal directory to both /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal and /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress. In other words, when I do an ls /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress, I get the contents on nas:/drupal, not nas:/wordpress.

If I do a df on both systems I get:

WEB1:

```
root@web1:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        30G  4.8G   24G  18% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  6.3M  457M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   21M   40M  35% /boot
nas:/drupal      15G  3.8G   11G  28% /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal
nas:/wordpress   15G  3.8G   11G  28% /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1001
```

WEB2:

```
root@web2:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        30G  3.2G   25G  12% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  6.3M  457M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   21M   40M  35% /boot
nas:/drupal      15G  3.8G   11G  28% /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1001
```

So it looks like WEB2 is not mounting the nas:/wordpress share.

I should note that both nas:/drupal and nas:/wordpress have exactly the same permissions.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: nfsstat -m on WEB2 gives the following result:

<snip>

     /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress from nas:/drupal
     Flags:     rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.34.0.40,mountvers=3,mountport=34053,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.34.0.40

</snip>

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress` on web2 ? Is it a symlink?

Comment: It is not a symlink.

    ls -ld /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 08:56 /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/

Comment: You have set the same `fsid=0` in the exports for both filesystems only for web2, but they are probably different filesystems.

Comment: Yup, I had just noticed that and made the change, and lo and behold everything is fine now.  But that does not explain why the two systems treated the mount differently.  I would have expected WEB1 to exhibit the same behavior as WEB2.  If it had I probably would have figured out the fsid issue sooner.

Comment: You don't have `fsid=0` set for the `.10` client so each machine will see different views of the NFS server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `fsid=0` value.

If we look at the `exports` entries we can split them into the two hosts:

```
10.34.0.10(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
10.34.0.20(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
```

So for the `.10` client the exports will have different FSIDs, but on the `.20` client, both shares will appear to have the same FSID.

Thus the `.10` client will see both exports correctly, but the `.20` will be confused.

Remove the `,fsid=0` value and things should work correctly for both clients.